# Pass Text to RaisedButton OnTap - Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm new to Flutter and I'm having a lot of trouble with a tic tac toe game. It works in the console, but I can't figure out how to get the game to work in the GUI I've built.

I know I need some kind of array for the game buttons, but I'm not sure how to implement this. I've built the game board with rows and columns like this:

```
      body: new Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  //Start of the 1st Row
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      // Button 0 in 1st Row
                      RaisedButton(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        onPressed: () {
                          _button0();
                        },
                        child: new Text(_mBoard[0],
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 40.0,
                              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                            )),
                        color: Colors.grey[300],
                      ),
```

This is _button0 that's called in the first RaisedButton's onPressed function. They go up to 8.

```
  void _button0() {
    setState(() {
      if (_mBoard[0] == humanPlayer || _mBoard[0] == computerPlayer) {
        return;
      } else if (win == 0) {
        if (turn == 0) {
          _mBoard[0] = humanPlayer;
          _text = humanPlayer + " MOVED, O's TURN";
          turn = 1;
          win = checkWinner();
          checkGameOver(win);
          displayBoard();
        }
        if ((turn == 1) && (win == 0)) {
          turn = 0;
          computerTurn();
          win = checkWinner();
          checkGameOver(win);
          displayBoard();
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Print board to console:

```
void displayBoard() {
  print(_mBoard[0] + " | " + _mBoard[1] + " | " + _mBoard[2]);
  print("-----------");
  print(_mBoard[3] + " | " + _mBoard[4] + " | " + _mBoard[5]);
  print("-----------");
  print(_mBoard[6] + " | " + _mBoard[7] + " | " + _mBoard[8]);
}
```

I expect the user's selection of a RaisedButton to display an "X" and the computer's selection to display an "O".

Answer (score 0):

You included both the part where _mBoard value updated and displayBoard() method inside setState(). Once you call setState(), it will notify StatefulWidget to update view. But you're calling displayBoard() inside setState, and this method doesn't have updated _mBoard value yet.

There are two ways to solve this,

- Passing _mBoard as parameter to displayBoard(_mBoard) , so it's going to access local _mBoard value not state value.
- Calling displayBoard after setState() called.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried to pass _mBoard to displayBoard for each _button: void _button0(String mBoard)...displayBoard(_mBoard[0]). And then for each RaisedButton's onPressed: onPressed: () { _button0(_mBoard[0]);}. But the game board still only prints in the console. Was this the right way to implement this?

Comment: From the code above, I can't see the part you render board view. Can you show me the part you actually pass _mBoard to build the view?

Comment: I actually figured out how to do it. I passed _mBoard into each of the RaisedButton widgets. I updated it above: new Text(_mBoard[0],... This allows the buttons to display and "X" or "O". Thanks for your help!